# Access to functions and local state from Component in a separate Component ( not direct siblings )

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am currently working with some data in a React project that needs to be dispatched, when a button is clicked from an outside component.

These components are not direct siblings (more like distant cousins) and are each nested in multiple separate components.
They do share a common component that is several levels up.
I do not wish to bog the top level parent component down with any functions.

What I have toyed around with:

- An idea of creating a shared function file that could be imported and
  added to the context props for the parent component.
- Passing the state data from one component into redux, then accessing it when the button is clicked in the other component.

CompA.tsx

```
export const CompA<CompAProps> = ({...}: CompAProps) => {

const [stateArray, setStateArray] = useState<StatePropName[] | undefined>();

  const handleSetArray = () => {
     dispatch(
        postDataArray(stateArray)
     );
  };

//Setting state is handled by another func

  return (<>.....</>);
}
```

CompB.tsx

```
export const CompB<CompBProps> = ({...}:CompBProps) => {

  const executeCompAFunc = () => {
     //...execute the function in CompA to dispatch
  };

  return (
     <>
        <button onClick={executeCompAFunc}></button>
     </>);
}
```

The result would see that when the button in `CompB` is clicked, the function in `CompA` is executed.

Is this even possible?

Comment: React components don't call internal functions in other React components. Lift the state/callbacks to the common ancestor and pass down as props. See [Lifting State Up](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and/or [Sharing State Between Components](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components) for details.

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you for the comment!
In this given instance, I am not looking to lift the state to the parent component, as it is required to stay free of any of its children's state objects. While the parent does pass down its own state as props, I was inquiring if it was at all possible to have the two components communicate directly with each other to access data, while both are rendered on the screen.
Will dive a bit deeper.

Comment: Two *independent* components *can* "communicate" with each other, but this typically is done via *some* "shared common state/handlers". You might try looking for a solution outside React though, like [window events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) or web sockets, etc.